# How to get input id of datepicker in c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using datapicker jquery but it is not able to get Input Id in C#.If i give runat=server ,i can call the input id in c#,but it does not work in page. Can anyone help me for that, I am new to Dnn. Any answer would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
enter code here
<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input id="datepicker"   type="text"  />

</p>

</div>
```

Comment: What do u mean by Id, JQuery DatePicker is bound to text box and u can access ID and name of TextBox in the code behind

Comment: i need control id in c# ,i want get this input value and save to database.i will paste my code

Comment: Can you explain/show what your exact code is and how you are trying to access server and client side ?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ruat="server" ID="txtDate" ></asp:TextBox> <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

     $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();       

    });   

   </script>

Comment: if i call string value=txtDate.Text , i am getting error in edit.aspx page

Answer (score 3):

Use TextBox with DatePicker

```
<asp:TextBox ruat="server" ID="txtDate" ></asp:TextBox>
```

To access it use `ClientID`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

     $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();       

    });   

   </script>
```

*EDIT: Based on the comments*

After defining your `txtDate` in aspx page with `runat="server"` you can access it in code behind like:

```
string value = txtDate.Text;
```

Comment: ya i tried i am not able to call control id in c# if i use textbox

Comment: @user1490276, make sure you have `runat="server"` in your aspx page for the textbox, and then you can access its Text Property like `string value = txtDate.Text;`

Comment: @user1490276, plz post your aspx page and part of code behind where you are accessing the field, in your question

Answer (score 1):

yep because when you add runat server the id get renamed by asp try using somethink like this
setting the client id mode static if you are using .net 4.0

or if you do not use .net 4.0 then try this

```
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker"  ClientIDMode="Static  type="text" runat="server"  />
```

or if you do not use .net 4.0 then try this

```
$("#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>").datepicker();
```

Comment: @Rab Nawaz who is PO and where are his comments

Comment: @Rab Nawaz he expains that when he is using runat="server" he can acess it but when not he cannt therefore he is asking how can I access it on both clint side and server side

Comment: your answer was useful  ,its working fine ,i am using one checkbox to display today date if i unchecked that it as to work , it is not working ,i will paste my code please let me

Comment: <p>Date: <input id="datepicker"  ClientIDMode="Static  type="text" runat="server"  />


    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="today's date"  />

Comment: c# code  g.Date = datepicker.Value;
           
           
            if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                datepicker.Visible = false;

                g.Date = DateTime.Today.ToString();


            }
            else
            {
                datepicker.Visible = true;
            }
where i am doing worng

Answer (score 0):

You can use CssClass of textbox to get datepicker in following way:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="DatepickerInput" />
```

You can use jquery code in following way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".DatepickerInput").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });

});
```